# Virtual box ubuntu VM with 2 network adapters

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running an ubuntu server 20.04 LTS image on a virtual box VM without a lot of wisdom here. There is 2 Python apps/scripts that each require a separate network adapter if running both scripts on the same machine at the same time (which I want to do). Is it possible to create a VM and define multiple virtual network adapters to use within the Linux VM environment?

I know the default is IP for inside the VM is `10.0.2.15/24` this is what I use to SSH into the VM from my Windows environment.

[image]

Would I just define this additional network adapter here maybe something like `10.0.2.16/24` which I think is a DHCP process from the virtual box? hopefully this makes sense any tips greatly appreciated...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can have two NAT adapters in Virtual Box. You cannot do this in VMware Workstation. I looked in the VBOX documentation and do not see support for 2 NAT connections.

What you can try is a USB Wired or Wireless card plugged into the Host machine and then do USB Passthrough and connect the guest to the USB card and also with a NAT connection to the Host.

If you need two network connections, you can try VMware ESX host or a Hyper-V host.